# How static calls are mocked with java agent like in jmockit?

Tags: java, mocking, jmockit

I came to know that Jmockit does not use custom class loader to mock the static call but instead uses the java agent .

I am aware of doing it throughcustom class loader. Can anyone explain how java agent help here at high level ?

I believe  java agent  must be intercepting the call and  call stub instead of original implementation .
 But how java agent helps here in interception as its usually done by proxy ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remember with a Java Agent you can manipulate the class objects as they are loaded. So JMockit can just insert anything into the class it wants. or needs.

Here you find a tutorial that gives an introduction about Java Agents and how to create some: http://www.javabeat.net/introduction-to-java-agents/

Comment: you said first class are loaded in class loader(not custom class loader) , once loaded java agent manipulate the byte code itself in loaded instance right ? If true, what point of time does java agent actually manipulate the class definition ? if just after class loaded how java agent get to know that class loading is complete for any class ?

Comment: Did you at all read the link I gave you above? The agent registers transformers in the Instrumentation instance of the agent premain method and then the JVM invokes theses transformers when a class is loaded. But actually I think that is not what JMockit it does, as you can use JMockit without the Java Agent. The Agent does only do some initialization, that you can do another way.

Answer (score 0):

java agent provides the capability of re-defining the content of class that is loaded at run-time.

So what it does replace the actual static method with your stub implementation at run time